# Adding velocity to 2d sprite in c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, flappy-bird-clone

hi i was wondering if someone could help me fix practice code (i make practice codes before i make the real thing because its just how i roll) it is basically an object that requires the user to click on the screen in order for it to not touch the ground much like flappy bird however although i have applied gravity correctly to the sprite i cannot fix the velocity section (i coded is to every time the user clicks with his mouse or taps the space key the object will move up like flappy bird)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BirdMovment : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public Vector3 flapVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f; 

    bool didFlap = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void update (){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
        {
            didFlap = true; 
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Velocity += gravity* Time.deltaTime;

        if (didFlap) {
            didFlap = false;
            Velocity += flapVelocity;

        }
        Velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (Velocity, maxSpeed);

        transform.position += Velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

can you please fix the error as every time i set the velocity in unity for the sprite ad run the program the sprite just keeps on falling and no matter how much i click or tap the space key the sprite does not stop falling even if i increase the velocity

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the correct Update function is with a capital U, so `Update()` instead of `update()`. Then, since you're not doing anything with physics, you can do everything in `Update` and not use `FixedUpdate` at all. So you can remove the `didFlap` variable and add to `Velocity` directly inside the `if (Input.GetKeyDown ...)` block. Furthermore, regarding gravity, you're multiplying it twice with `Time.deltaTime`there, so remove the first one. That should get you started.

Comment: Did you read my answer? The update method name is incorrect, it won't be called by Unity unless it's correct.